# How can I convert unicode values in a string "U+XXXXXX" to the corresponding characters in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I accept from backend the following json

```
 {
        "id": "f33919f6-3554-4246-9e78-bca3a690c119",
        "title": "Category3",
        "slug": "category3",
        "hex_up": "#eb4034",
        "hex_down": "#80302a",
        "emoji": "U+1F602",
        "parent_id": "aa3f651b-f068-4ae1-a9d8-a18a9945b111"
    }
```

There is a field  **"emoji": "U+1F602",**

I need show emoji icon like  in UILabel
I tried to google and found results like

```
let scalarValue = UnicodeScalar(emojiString)
let myString = String(scalarValue!)
```

Unfortunately app crashes at the second line.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `U+...` syntax in Swift. (There is a `\u{...}` syntax that does the same thing, but it's not necessary here.)

You'll need to parse the String yourself:

```
func parseUnicode(_ string: String) -> String? {
    guard string.hasPrefix("U+"), // Make sure it's a U+ string
          let value = Int(string.dropFirst(2), radix: 16), // Convert to Int
          let scalar = UnicodeScalar(value) // Convert to UnicodeScalar
          else { return nil }

    return String(scalar) // Convert to String
}

if let myString = parseUnicode(emoji) { ... }
```

Don't use `!` here. The `U+...` string may be invalid, and you wouldn't want to crash in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply apply a string transform from `"Hex/Unicode"` to `"Any"` (a set of all characters):

```
"U+1F602".applyingTransform(.init("Hex/Unicode-Any"), reverse: false)   // ""
```

or as instance properties of StringProtocol to encode/decode from/to hexa unicode:

---

```
extension StringTransform {
    static let unicodeToAny: Self = .init("Hex/Unicode-Any")
    static let anyToUnicode: Self = .init("Any-Hex/Unicode")
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var decodingHexaUnicode: String {
        applyingTransform(.unicodeToAny, reverse: false)!
    }
    var encodingHexaUnicode: String {
        applyingTransform(.anyToUnicode, reverse: false)!
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let hexaUnicode = "U+1F602"
let emoji = hexaUnicode.decodingHexaUnicode       // ""
let unicodeFromEmoji = emoji.encodingHexaUnicode  // "U+1F602"
```

Comment: I agree this works, but (as someone who spends a lot of time reading Unicode specs and had never seen this particular transform) I think this answer needs to explain how you would discover that "Hex-Any" was the correct transformation here. What does "Any" represent here in particular? Is this appropriate for all Unicode  uses?

Comment: Really, with a slash instead of a hyphen? I'd rather write the code myself than guess what magical strings I found on the Internet do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app crashed is due to the fact that the scalarValue you attempted to initialize is `nil`, and you're force-unwrapping using (`!`) that nil value on line 2. Rob's answer shows how to unwrap the optional safely.

You can get the emoji by using the value following the `U+`. So you'll need to drop the first two characters of the string. So use this code to accomplish that:

```
let parsedEmoji = emojiString.substring(from:2)
```

Now you'll convert that emoji unicode using the code below.

```
let emoji = String(UnicodeScalar(Int(parsedEmojiHex,radix: 16)!)!)

print(emoji)
```